# Is there a way we can select a host tags dynamically in "Node Filter" section based on the value selected in "Options" field?

Tags: rundeck

Is there a way we can select a host tags dynamically in "Node Filter" section based on the value selected in "Options" field ?

Currently I need to run a job on different set of hosts based on the "Options" field selected. Let say i have two options like "Group 1" and "Group 2" . And when i select "Group 1" option a particular set of host tags has to get selected and when selecting "Group 2" another set of host tags has to get selected and executed on those hosts. By doing this we can run that job dynamically on different set of hosts depending on our need.

Thanks,
M. Kannan.

Answer (score 2):

Group your servers using a common tag, create an option that is a list of the different groups tags, then reference that option in the node filter for the job using "`tags: ${option.[option_name]}`".

For example, I have nodes tagged as `DEV, TEST, or PROD.` I defined a corresponding list option named `server_env` that contains these same three categories. For the node filter, I used "`tags: ${option.server_env}`".

HTH

Answer (score 0):

The best option that our team has found is to:

1. Create a Workflow that takes your original options
2. Create a script that maps your option to the filters you want
3. In the same script call the rundeck job you want to run and provide the variable containing the desired filters